# Node.js - Formidable upload with XHR

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I try to implement a simple XHR upload to Node.js (via [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)). The problem is that if I set

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

node gives me error:

```
Error: bad content-type header, no multipart boundary
```

If I set boundary to just a random string nothing happens. The browser just hangs on POST and waits for server response.

The point is that if I use formidable with regular synchronous POST everything works fine.

Anyone tried to use [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) with XHR upload?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out. I made a small bug on the client side.

Here is the **working expample of XHR upload with Formidable**

You **don't need** to set any boundaries or special headers.

**Client**

```
var formData = new FormData();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var onProgress = function(e) {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = (e.loaded/e.total)*100;
  }
};

var onReady = function(e) {
 // ready state
};

var onError = function(err) {
  // something went wrong with upload
};

formData.append('files', file);
xhr.open('post', '/up', true);
xhr.addEventListener('error', onError, false);
xhr.addEventListener('progress', onProgress, false);
xhr.send(formData);
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onReady, false);
```

**Server**

```
app.post('/up', function(req, res) {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = __dirname + '/tmp';
  form.encoding = 'binary';

  form.addListener('file', function(name, file) {
    // do something with uploaded file
  });

  form.addListener('end', function() {
    res.end();
  });

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "bad content-type header, no content-type". Not really sure how to get round this?

Comment: @pagewil Try setting enctype="multipart/form-data" on your <form> tag

Comment: Could you share what was actually the problem on the client side, which fixed it?

Comment: Great! It helps. Thanks! Did you find out why can't specify the header type?

Comment: @BrickYang You should not add Content-Type, because if you do this you should include boundary delimiter like this "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydxvCgHrARZTMcsKt", while you _*cannot*_ access boundary delimiter at FormData actually. (And I should read answers more carefully as I spent couple of hours to understand whats going on while I had right answer just before my eyes)

Answer (score 2):

I tried a couple of different things with Formidable and was never able to get it to accept a XHR upload.  Here is what I ended up doing for a file upload using express.

```
app.post('/upload', function (req,res){
  if(req.xhr){
    var fSize = req.header('x-file-size'),
    fType = req.header('x-file-type'), 
    basename = require('path').basename, 
    fName = basename(req.header('x-file-name')), 
    ws = fs.createWriteStream('./temp/'+fName); 
    req.on('data', function(data) { 
      ws.write(data);
    });
```

Hope this helps.