# uploading very large files (5gb to 15gb)

Tags: php, ruby, node.js, large-file-upload

I'm trying to figure out different ways to achieve very large file uploads/downloads. I'm new to node.js and it looks like it may be the answer to my question but before dive in I need to be sure this way I can manage files uploads (5 to 15 Gb) without any memory issues or similar.
I can consider using php / ruby or .net as technology (I don't know much about node.js but if it works I'll study enough to solve my problems).

What's your opinion / experience ?

thanks

Comment: It's not a good idea to give users possibility to upload that big files, IMO. However if you are going to use php you have to modify `php.ini` you can simply find configurations in google.

Comment: no php.ini and max_memory_limit stuff is definitely not an option. And unfortunately uploading very large files is the main client request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to break the file into chunks, and deal with the chunks.

I've seen someone do this using mongodb gridFS (http://fuz.io)

take a look at http://www.componentix.com/blog/13/file-uploads-using-nodejs-once-again as it may give you some ideas.

Comment: ok.. that's a starting point. Is there any way to make rails app and node.js app work together?

Comment: Yes there is, dead simple way is to have rails render the form and submit to the node server. You can also do it in a more dynamic method adding javascript to ruby side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884382/node-js-formidable-upload-with-xhr/6890081#6890081 has some details about how that can be done.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I mean something related to sessions variables or similar. Since it's sopposed to be an app where users upload files and specify other users to share with.

Comment: not sure about session variables, but you could share a database between both apps, or use something like redis pub/sub